# Java Future : How to unblock Main thread while executing Aysnc call

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, future, completable-future

When I do async call using ExecutorService, it returns Future Object. Based on the boolean value it returns, I have to log the status of the async call.

But when I try to call the method get method from the future object, it blocks the main thread execution.

Is it possible to unblock the main thread execution?

```
public class FutureExample {

    static HystrixCommand<Boolean> hystrixCommand;

    public FutureExample(HystrixCommand<Boolean> hystrixCommand){
        FutureExample.hystrixCommand = hystrixCommand;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {


        Boolean something = asyncCall();

        if(something) {
            System.out.println("Future task is done");
        }

        System.out.println("Don't wait for async call");

    }

    private static Boolean asyncCall() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        Future<Boolean> response = hystrixCommand.queue(); // Aysnc Call to remote server

        return response.get(); //this is blocking main thread
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes you can, simply don't call `response.get();`. Or you can wait for a second and call `response.isDone()` instead

Comment: But I want to log based on aysnc response :(

Comment: So, you have to either wait for the operation to complete (e.g. by calling `get()`) to get the result or continue execution and not care about result. You can also start another thread and call `response.get();` in it and then log result when it's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good thing about futures is to be able to release threads until the answer arrives.
So I recommend you to use a Future implementation, like CompletableFuture:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        return hystrixCommand.queue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}, executorService);
```

This will work on another thread and when that future is over it will be done.

Comment: What’s the point of wrapping an async call into another asyc call?

Comment: Well seen, I have put the focus on an example of how to make a call out of the main Thread so that it would be understood as not blocking it.

Comment: According to the question, the call `hystrixCommand.queue()` is already asynchronous, non-blocking, returning a `Future`. The actual blocking operation was invoking `get()` on the future. Of course, your code is not invoking `get()`, thus solving the problem, but that could have been achieved much simpler, by just doing `hystrixCommand.queue();` as a statement. Even unnecessary wrapping into another asynchronous operation can be done as simple as `executorService.submit( () -> hystrixCommand.queue());` The `CompletableFuture`, as used here, is just an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1):

According to [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--), `get()` method waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

If you want to get the result once the task is completed, use `isDone()` function, which returns `true` if the task completed (normally, exceptionally, etc.). And invoke `get()` afterwards.

Also, you can use `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` function to wait only for the given period of time. In this case the main thread will be "unblocked" automatically if either the time is out or the task has completed.

Comment: Yes, I understood what each of these methods does. But I don't want to block the main thread.

Comment: Then don't block it. It gets blocked only when you invoke `get()` method. You want to get the result once the task completed, right? Use `isDone()` to check if it's so. It does not block the main thread. Do some other job while your task is being performed (i.e. `isDone() == false`). And when you're ready, come back and check again if the task is done.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute code in the main thread while the async task is running, you will need to redesign your `asyncCall` method to make it return a future instead.

An example:

```
private static Future<Boolean> asyncCall() 
      throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    return hystrixCommand.queue(); 
}
```

This way, the main method makes the call regarding when to block/wait:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
     throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    Future<Boolean> something = asyncCall();

    //do something while async call is running

    //to check whether it's done running:
    if(something.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Future task is done");
    }

    //when you're finally ready to wait:
    System.out.println("Waiting for async call to finish");
    Boolean result = something.get();
}
```

Comment: But async call takes more than 2 secs, don't want to block main thread till the time. Is it possible to log in a separate thread or any callback method?

Comment: @NaghaveerGowda You can run other code where I marked with the `//do something while async call is running` comment, and block only when you need the result. If what you need is a callback, then please update the question.